# How to use Strophe.js in ionic 2 for chat with XMPP?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, xmpp, chat, strophe

I want to create a chat module in ionic platform then i got example from [here](http://www.arjunsk.com/html5/part-2-ionic-xmpp-chat-client-using-strophe-js/), but this solution looks older and its using ionic 1 , using `$scope` and and code is written in .js files which is including below mentioned files...

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/routes.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
```

In my application .ts files are used and different methods for controlling and routing and this code is using different methods. and i'm unable to find example of using strophe.js with ionic 2 and typescript code. can anyone help me? by giving example, link or steps of using strophe.js in ionic 2 such as how to make connection, how to get archived messages, manage presense, get contact list etc.